# Remove every x lines from text input

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I'm looking to grep some log files with a few surrounding lines, but then discard the junk lines from the matches.  To make matters worse, the stupid code outputs the same exception twice so I want to junk every other grep match.  I don't know that there's a good way to skip every other grep match when also including surrounding lines, so I'm good to do it all in one.

So let's say we have the following results from grep:

```
InterestingContext1
lkjsdf
MatchExceptionText1
--
kjslkj
lskjlk
MatchExceptionText2
--
InterestingContext3
lkjsdf
MatchExceptionText3
--
kjslkj
lskjlk
MatchExceptionText4
--
```

Obviously the grep match is "MatchExceptionText" (simplified, of course).  So I'd like to pipe this to something where I can remove lines 2,5,6,7,8 and then repeat that pattern, so the results look like this:

```
InterestingContext1
MatchExceptionText1
--
InterestingContext3
MatchExceptionText3
--
```

The repeating is where things get tricky for me.  I know sed can just remove certain line numbers but I don't know how to group them into groups of 8 lines and repeat that cut in all the groups.

Any ideas?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` can do modular arithemetic so printing conditional on the number of lines read mod 8 should allow you to repeat the pattern.

```
awk 'NR%8 ~ /[134]/' file
```

Comment: So if your offsets are correct, `awk 'NR%8 ~ /[134]/' file`.  Using a regex here is a bit of a cheat; be aware that `[134]` is a character class which happens to work here because all possible modulo values are a single digit.

Comment: I read it as mod 8 since the pattern repeats every 8 lines.  Cameron is counting from 1 but after applying modulo we need to count from 0.

Comment: You are correct and in fact I already revised my comment to that effect.  Sorry for being too quick to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Sed can do it:

```
sed -n 'N;s/\n.*//;N;N;p;N;N;N;N' filename
```

**EDIT:**

Come to think of it, this is a little better:

```
sed -n 'p;n;n;N;p;n;n;n;n' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk you can split the input at appropriate record separators and print the wanted output, eg.:

```
awk 'NR%2 {print $1, $3}' RS='--\n' ORS='\n--\n' OFS='\n' infile
```

Output:

```
InterestingContext1
MatchExceptionText1
--
InterestingContext3
MatchExceptionText3
--
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'p;n;n;p;n;p;n;n;n;n' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "s/^.*\n//;x;s/^/²/

/^²\{1\}$/ b print
/^²\{3\}$/ b print
/^²\{4\}$/ b print
/^²\{7\}$/ b print
/^²\{8\}$/ b print

b cycle

: print
x;
# your treatment begin
p
# your treatment stop
x

: cycle
/^²\{8\}$/ s/.*//
x
" YourFile
```

Mainly for reference for kind of "case of" with relative line number, just have to change the number in `/^²\{YourLineNumber\}$/` for take the other relative line position.

Don't forget the last line number that reset the cycle

- First part take the line and prepare the relative line counter
- Second part is the *case of*
- Third part is the treatment (here a print)
- Last part is the reset of the cycle counter if needed